# How to decode .dxf files?

Tags: decode, autocad, cad, dxf, g-code

I would like to convert the drawings inside a .dxf file into g-code. There are tools doing that but I would like to code it myself. So, the very first part is to decode the .dxf format. Yet, the contents of the .dxf file does not look easy to decipher.

I downloaded a .dxf file [here](https://3axis.co/circles-dxf-file/eo4kry7j/) and opened it in a text editor.

I am also referring to this [manual](http://images.autodesk.com/adsk/files/autocad_2012_pdf_dxf-reference_enu.pdf). It looks like what is inside a .dxf file is mostly style and configuration information and I tend to omit almost everything. So, **1. can you specify attributes that should not be omitted, if there are any?**

As far as I know the figures are divided into multiple ENTITIES in a .dxf file. Therefore, I am only copy pasting the SECTION of ENTITIES. Note that there are 6 SECTIONS in the file and the last section (<s>BLOCKS</s> OBJECTS) is the longest one although I don't know what that part represents (Would be nice if you could explain).

In the code below, 10 and 20 should be representing X and Y positions and 42 should be representing the bulge. It is kind of possible to track the polyline. I consider extracting information from the file by using the TITLES as navigation points as well as the numbers like 10, 20 and 42. But there are two polylines below. So, **2. which polyline should I take into consideration and what is the purpose of the other?**

```
  0
SECTION
  2
ENTITIES
  0
LWPOLYLINE
  5
72    # What
330   # are
1F    # these
100   # numbers?
AcDbEntity
  8
Layer 1
100
AcDbPolyline
 90
       12
 70
     1
 43    # Constant width (optional; default = 0)
0.0
 10
11.7511418685121
 20
14.9867256637168
 42
1.0
 10
3.31114186851211
 20
14.9867256637168
 10
-0.0132743362831871
 20
14.9867256637168
 10
-0.0132743362831871
 20
11.72
 42
1.0
 10
-0.0132743362831871
 20
3.28
 10
-0.0132743362831871
 20
0.0398230088495577
 10
3.28
 20
0.039823008849557
 42
1.0
 10
11.72
 20
0.0398230088495577
 10
15.0132743362832
 20
0.0398230088495577
 10
15.0132743362832
 20
3.28
 42
1.0
 10
15.0132743362832
 20
11.72
 10
15.0132743362832
 20
14.9867256637168
  0
LWPOLYLINE
  5
73
330
1F
100
AcDbEntity
  8
Layer 1
100
AcDbPolyline
 90
       12
 70
     1
 43
0.0
 10
12.6544611051008
 20
15.9867256637168
 10
16.0132743362832
 20
15.9867256637168
 10
16.0132743362832
 20
12.6233192365887
 42
-0.823684764724874
 10
16.0132743362832
 20
2.37668076341128
 10
16.0132743362832
 20
-0.960176991150442
 10
12.6233192365887
 20
-0.960176991150442
 42
-0.823684764724874
 10
2.37668076341128
 20
-0.960176991150443
 10
-1.01327433628319
 20
-0.960176991150442
 10
-1.01327433628319
 20
2.37668076341128
 42
-0.823684764724874
 10
-1.01327433628319
 20
12.6233192365887
 10
-1.01327433628319
 20
15.9867256637168
 10
2.40782263192339
 20
15.9867256637168
 42
-0.823684764724874
  0
ENDSEC
```

---

#### Related Questions

- [What fields to take into consideration in a .dxf file to obtain an accurate G-Code?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/68967860/2287576)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The last section (`BLOCKS`) is the longest one although I don't know
> what that part represents (Would be nice if you could explain).

The purpose of the [`BLOCKS`](http://docs.autodesk.com/ACD/2011/ENU/filesDXF/WSfacf1429558a55de185c428100849a0ab7-5e01.htm) section is summaried in the manual you referred to:

> The `BLOCKS` section contains an entry for each block reference in the drawing.

Think of a block as a group of entities that are grouped together as one element. The block has:

- Origin
- Rotation
- Scale

Such blocks are **referenced** in the drawing itself and each **instance** of the block is called an `INSERT`.

So when you walk your `ENTITIES` section and you hit an [`INSERT`](http://docs.autodesk.com/ACD/2011/ENU/filesDXF/WS1a9193826455f5ff18cb41610ec0a2e719-7a04.htm) entity, you then have to find its **handle** in the `BLOCK` table and process the elements accordingly.

---

There are some DXF codes that are common to many entities and they are not always listed with the information for a specific entity type (like `LWPOLYLINE`).

Look at this [complete list](http://help.autodesk.com/view/OARX/2018/ENU/?guid=GUID-3F0380A5-1C15-464D-BC66-2C5F094BCFB9) for those numbers:

> - 5: Entity handle; text string of up to 16 hexadecimal digits (fixed)
> - 330: Soft-pointer handle; arbitrary soft pointers to other objects within same DXF file or drawing. Translated during `INSERT` and `XREF`
>   operations
> - 100: Subclass data marker (with derived class name as a string). Required for all objects and entity classes that are derived from
>   another concrete class. The subclass data marker segregates data
>   defined by different classes in the inheritance chain for the same
>   object. This is in addition to the requirement for DXF names for each
>   distinct concrete class derived from ObjectARX (see Subclass Markers)

This [page](http://help.autodesk.com/view/OARX/2018/ENU/?guid=GUID-3610039E-27D1-4E23-B6D3-7E60B22BB5BD) is also useful.

---

> Why are there 2 `LWPOLYLINES` in the first place and why is it not only one `BLOCK`-`ENDBLK` pair?

If you read through the section about [`BLOCKS`](http://help.autodesk.com/view/OARX/2018/ENU/?guid=GUID-66D32572-005A-4E23-8B8B-8726E8C14302) you'll see:

> ### Model Space and Paper Space Block Definitions
>
> Three empty definitions always appear in the `BLOCKS` section. They are
> titled `*Model_Space`, `*Paper_Space` and `*Paper_Space0`. These definitions
> manifest the representations of *model space* and *paper space* as block
> definitions internally. The internal name of the first paper space
> layout is *Paper_Space, the second is *Paper_Space0, the third is
> *Paper_Space1, and so on.

Comment: Thank you. The links in your answer helped me understand better. Group Code is like the name of a field and in the next line we enter the relevant value. But I did not get everything about blocks. For instance in the file I shared there are 3 BLOCK-ENDBLK pairs, but there are 2 LWPLOYLINES. Why are there 2 LWPOLYLINES in the first place and why is it not only one BLOCK-ENDBLK pair?

Comment: @Xfce4 Please see my updated answer. I think when a new drawing is created it includes two paper space layouts and maybe they include the 'LWPOLYLINE' objects. Hard to tell without oopening the actual DXF file in a viewer. Becareful about asking multiple questions in one.  If I have aswered your question then please upvote it and accept it. Thanks!

Comment: I opened the dxf file in an online viewer and there were two thin polylines parallel to each other. That is why there are two polyline ENTITIES in the file. I thought the shape in the [link](https://3axis.co/circles-dxf-file/eo4kry7j/) was a single polyline drawn with a thick line.

Comment: @Xfce4 Yes, I can see why you would think it to be a thick like. The image is a bit misleading. But, you can apply a solid hatch fill to that area to fill it.

Comment: If I apply hatch, will there be a single LWPOLYLINE with a higher thickness value? Actually it is better if I try and see. I think I will download a free CAD software on my PC. Thanks a lot for your help. It was very kind of you.

Comment: @Xfce4 You would have three elements. You could delete one element and set line width to the line instead. But, try in an app as you say because this is outside the scope of your question. Happy to help.