# What is the structure of a DXF BLOCK_RECORD and DICTIONARY and how is it used?

Tags: autocad, dxf

I am creating a feature to convert data into a DXF file. Sadly because of limitations I cannot use one of the existing frameworks, so am very simply trying to write my own.

I am at the point where I can define a block (group of shapes and lines) with attributes, and insert these at any location and orientation. But I would like to add additional functionality by creating visibility states for the block. Because of this complexity I am lead to believe I need to declare block_record and dictionaries.

I can reference the DXF documentation which gives an explanation about various group codes to use, but I cannot find any reference material to explain how any of this works. Creating the objective block in AutoCAD and then saving as a DXF to inspect becomes difficult as this is very padded.

What I would like to do is extract from the AutoCAD generated DXF, just the components I need to make my block function.

Starting with the BLOCKS section, I can extract the definition for my block, however it references several dictionaries and has different 330 group codes. So I need to copy the dictionaries section, however this appears to be approximately 12000 lines for an empty project with one block defined but not on the workspace. I do not know how to either extract what I require, or write the basics from scratch.

Any pointers would be appreciated as reading material is thin on this. Or a basic example of the minimum requirements to create and use a block with visibility states.

Comment: Some information about block structures I have collected by creating `ezdxf`: https://ezdxf.readthedocs.io/en/stable/dxfinternals/block_management.html

Answer (score 1):

It you look here ([How to decode .dxf files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68946385/how-to-decode-dxf-files)) you will see a link to:

> [Common Group Codes for Entities (DXF)](https://help.autodesk.com/view/OARX/2018/ENU/?guid=GUID-3610039E-27D1-4E23-B6D3-7E60B22BB5BD)

You referred to `330`. The linked web page mentions:

> `330` Soft-pointer ID/handle to owner `BLOCK_RECORD` object.

If you look at the [`BLOCK`](https://help.autodesk.com/view/OARX/2018/ENU/?guid=GUID-66D32572-005A-4E23-8B8B-8726E8C14302) section it mentions:

> `5` Handle

Without a sample DXF to example it is hard to provide more information, but in summary:

1. The drawing should have a `BLOCK` record that defines the `BLOCK`. And it will have a unique `Handle`.
2. The drawing will then have **instances** of that block, referred to as `INSERT` entities and these will identify the `BLOCK` definition via `330`.

This is how I understand blocks to work in DWG / DXF files.

---

*I have not verified if my understanding of `330` is correct. I would need to examine your DXF file.*

Comment: I think the concept is still not clear to me about the 'block_record table'.
I am able to define a block in the blocks section, and use INSERT in the ENTITIES section. This happens without creating any block_record table. 
Because of this I do not understand what value the block_record table adds. Creating a simple structure for blocks and inserting entities (or drawing directly in entities) is all fairly well documented. However this tables section and the 'handle' section seem very poorly documented. I cannot find a very simple example of creating a block_record table for one block

Comment: @samp17 Start Autocad. Create a empty drawing. Define a block that has a circle. Insert that block once. Now export your drawing as dxf. The block will have a definition in the block table and an instance as an insert in the entities section. 

Note that all entities are in a model space or paper space block table record too, as mentioned in my linked answer.